# Data validation based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am adding a data validation list based on a cell value. If value in cell B29 = "text1" then add data validation in cell D29. If the cell B29 has a different value then a formula has to be added to cell D29 and the data validation has to be removed.

Here is an example of the macro:

```
If Range("B29").Value = "Text1" Then
Range("D29").Value = ""
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(B29)"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
ElseIf Range("B29").Value = "Value1" Then
 Range("D29").Formula = "=IF(Sheet2!B9,VLOOKUP(Sheet2!B8,'Team Target Tabel'!C2:E17,2,FALSE),"""")"
 Range("D29").Validation.Delete
ElseIf Range("B29").Value = "Value2" Then
 Range("D29").Formula = "=IF(Sheet2!B9,VLOOKUP(Sheet2!B8,'Team Target Tabel'!C2:E17,2,FALSE),"""")"
 Range("D29").Validation.Delete
ElseIf Range("B29").Value = "Value3" Then
 Range("D29").Formula = "=IF(Sheet2!B9,VLOOKUP(Sheet2!B8,'Team Target Tabel'!C2:E17,2,FALSE),"""")"
 Range("D29").Validation.Delete
 End If
End Sub
```

Cell B29 is also a data validation cell which has 4 values. If the value is text1 then cell D29 has to change into a data validation list but I have to run the macro manually to do this. When D29 is a data validation list and I change the value in cell B29 I have to run the macro again (manually) to change it back to the formula.

Comment: Please explain how is your macro not working

Comment: Cell B29 is also a data validation cell which has 4 values. If the value is text1 then cell D29 has to change into a data validation list but I have to run the macro manually to do this. When D29 is a data validation list and I change the value in cell B29 I have to run the macro again (manually) to change it back to the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture the Worksheet_change event to re-run the macro when `D29` changes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B29")) Is Nothing Then
        Call myMacroToChangeValidationOfD29
    End If
End Sub
```

BTW, why `With Selection.Validation` not `With Range("D29").Validation` ??

Comment: I indeed changed it to With Range("D29").Validation and used StrComp which  Lajos Arpad posted and it works like it should but I still need to run the macro manually. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Miksel not wrong, but you have a requirement which is to change the validation of `D29` whenever `B29` changes. The `Worksheet_Change` event is made for this. You need to add this handler to automate the running of the macro, add it (as in my answer) in the code of worksheet that contains your `B29` cell, and change the `call` to the correct name of your macro, the macro that you show in the OP.

Comment: I get an error message: runtime error 438. Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake in the syntax of `Intersect`. Please reconsider the edited code.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [StrComp](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/strcomp.php) to compare strings, example:

```
If StrComp(Range("B29").Value, "text1") = 0 Then
    'Something
End If
```

You want to check B29 against "text1", however, you are checking it against "Text1". You might have a problem of case sensitivity. Your else cases are similar, you could simplify them to a single else, like this:

```
If StrComp(Range("B29").Value, "text1") = 0 Then
Range("D29").Value = ""
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(B29)"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
Else
 Range("D29").Formula = "=IF(Sheet2!B9,VLOOKUP(Sheet2!B8,'Team Target Tabel'!C2:E17,2,FALSE),"""")"
 Range("D29").Validation.Delete
End Sub
```